# Which perfect squares can be written as the sum of two squares?

Tags: algorithms, contest-math

what perfect square number should be substracted from x so that resultant is perfect square number if solution doest not exist just tell not possible?

**note here x is also perfect square number**

**example x=25**

25-9=**16**(perfect square number)

here ans=9

**x=100**

100-36=**64**(perfect square number)

here ans=36

**x=100**

100-64=**36** whis perfect square number

here ans=64

when x=4 ,6,3 and so on
then no such answer will be exist

Comment: I would say $x$.

Comment: you have to tell a number except x

Comment: If $x$ is a perfect square, and you want to subtract a perfect square and get a perfect square, and you define perfect squares to be strictly positive (where $0$ doesn't count), then this is essentially asking to find [pythagorean triples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple).  Also, note that if one solution exist, a second exists as well.  I.e. if $x^2-a^2=b^2$ then also $x^2-b^2=a^2$

Comment: given x can you predict whether such treplet exist or not no matter how many such treplet exist with x

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit unclear what you're asking about, but here are a few related tidbits.

---

You should read about [Pythagorean triples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple). There are integers $(a,b,c)$ that satisfy

$$a^2 + b^2 = c^2$$

In this case $c^2$ is your $x$ and either $b^2$ or $a^2$ are possible values for what you subtract from your $x$.

---

You may also be interested in [Fermat's theorem on sums of two squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares), which answers the question of when a prime number can be written as a sum of two squares.

---

Given any integer, you can tell whether it can be written as the sum of two squares if you find its [prime factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization). **If all of the primes that are one less than multiples of four have *even exponents* in the prime factorization of your number**, then it can be written as the sum of two squares. Otherwise, it cannot. You should first read Fermat's theorem on writing primes as sums of two squares if you want to understand this more general result.

This is related to your original question because if $x$ can be written as the *sum* of two squares, then you know at least two possibilities for "perfect squares that can be subtracted from $x$ to get another perfect square"  ...

Comment: given perfect square number x  i just want to know that subtract any perfect square number  from x but result should also be a perfect square number in other word pythagores triple exist or not?

Comment: So your question is: which perfect squares can be written as the sum of two other perfect squares?

Comment: i am not  intrested in their values..but i just want to know wether such treplets exists or not

Comment: given perfect square no x whether it can be represented as sum of two perfect square no or not??